# Devuelve null en consola - querySelector y getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom, null

cuando quiero hacer que me devuelva lo que tengo en las etiquetas y coloco querySelector y getElementById me devuelve null en la consola, no entiendo cual es el problema si está todo bien escrito.
Por lo que veo aca si te lo ejecuta bien y no da el "null" que me da a mi, cual debe ser el error? Será que estoy usando LiveServer?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("h3"));
console.log(document.querySelector("p"));
console.log(document.getElementById("tituloh1"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM Uno</title>
    <script src="domunojs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<h3>Bienvenidos al DOM</h3>
<p>Mostrando parrafo en consola con querySelector</p>
<h1 id="tituloh1">GetElementById</h1>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tal vez sea porque al ejecutarse el código javascript aún no está cargado los elementos que están en `body`. Para descartar, prueba importando el script antes del cierre de la etiqueta `body`.

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo null si lo coloco antes de la etiqueta body. No entiendo que puede ser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas aquí puede se puede incluir código javascript sin necesidad de importarlo, ya que el comportamiento es diferente a comparación de que sea entregado por un servidor. Intenta utilizar el evento `DOMContentLoaded` para asegurar que el código javascript sea ejecutado posterior a la carga del DOM

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log(document.querySelector("h3"));
  console.log(document.querySelector("p"));
  console.log(document.getElementById("tituloh1"));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM Uno</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<h3>Bienvenidos al DOM</h3>
<p>Mostrando parrafo en consola con querySelector</p>
<h1 id="tituloh1">GetElementById</h1>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que estas colocando las llamadas a la consola en el archivo "domunojs.js" que está en la cabecera del documento html. El problema es que estas ejecutando las llamadas a la consola para mostrar los elementos que aun no se han cargado en el documento.
Para poder solucionarlo puedes probar dos cosas:

1. Colocar la etiqueta  donde llamas al archivo "domunojs.js" al final de la etiqueta

   ```
    <h3>Bienvenidos al DOM</h3>
    <p>Mostrando parrafo en consola con querySelector</p>
    <h1 id="tituloh1">GetElementById</h1>

    <script src="domunojs.js"></script>
   ```

Con eso podrás ver los elementos ya que el script se ejecutara justo despues de haber cargado el resto de la etiqueta , que es donde están los elementos cuyo contenido quieres ver en consola.

2. Puedes dejar la etiqueta script en la cabecera y editar el archivo "domuonjs.js" para definir una función que se ejecute cuando el documento html haya terminado de cargar usando un evento. Por ejemplo puedes utilizar el evento onload del objeto window:

   ```
    window.onload = function(){
      console.log(document.querySelector("h3"));
      console.log(document.querySelector("p"));
      console.log(document.getElementById("tituloh1"));
    }
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias es como decis!